# PHP File_get_contents error in connection

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a php file and all it contains is

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo file_get_contents("http://mywebsite.com/javascript-function.php");
?>
```

And for some reason it displays the following notice:

```
Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 24 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer in /home/sites/mywebsite.com/public_html/index.php on line 6 Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /home/sites/mywebsite.com/public_html/index.php on line 6
```

I have never come accross this message before so I have no idea what to do to solve it.

I have also tried using cURL but it outputs nothing and no error message.

Comment: Take a look at the error log file of the http server on `mywebsite.com`.

Comment: You mean, the php-script tries to fetch its own output via http? What are you trying to do? _Connection reset by peer_ means, the remote closed it without reading all data from the socket

Comment: Probably target web site using a user-agent policy or something like that, or your hosting's IP address is blocked on target computer.

Comment: I'm trying to create a bunch of php function files. It's a little complicated but I'm trying to make a file which will output javascript code because I am unable to put a javascript variable to PHP so I thought this method might work. On the file I'm trying to get, it has a function and at the end it has document.write(function-result); Does this method not work?

Comment: @Acidic Maybe it works when done right, I didn't get it fully, but in any case there should be no need to fetch it through http. Better load it from a local file

Comment: @Ctx I just need javascript code to be used in php. So I am trying to write the javascript code in an external file which will output some data and php will grab the outputted data.

Comment: Include and call the php code which generates the javascript directly into this php-script instead of trying to fetch the result through http

Comment: @Ctx But that's the problem, the code in the external file is Javascript, not php. So I need only the result of the javascript function in the external file, not the content of the file.

Comment: @Acidic Ah, now I understand you. Unfortunately javascript is not executed by the webserver, but only in a browser, so this will not work.

Comment: @Ctx So pretty much, it's absolutely impossible to get a javascript variable into php without ajax?

Comment: @Acidic Speaking generally, yes. I would advise you to open a new question where you describe the _real_ problem you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *connection reset by peer* error occurs in a datastream connection when either the remote host you are connecting to (i.e. *mywebsite.com* which you specified in the call to `file_get_contents`) terminates the socket connection on their end before the client is finished sending the request, or when the local network system detects a failure in connecting.

Some common root causes could be a firewall rule that is blocking the connection on either end or possibly a miss-configured web server. One way to narrow down the problem is to attempt accessing the same URL from a web browser on the same client that this script was run when the error occurred. If it works as expected, at least you know, it's not a firewall issue on the client. Begin digging into the web server's config files to troubleshoot the problem further. However, if the same problem occurs in a web browser then you should begin looking into your firewall rules on that client as well as the host's firewall rules if any.

Comment: Yeah I've tried heaps of different methods but I think it's my web host's fault. Some sort of setting/feature that needs adjusting I guess.

Comment: The firewall rule would _not_ lead to `Connection reset by peer`. `Connection refused` or `Connection timed out` would be possible.

Comment: Well I have no idea what it is then, I've tried just simply putting a .txt file in the root of my domain and using file_get_contents for it but the exact same error is showing.

Comment: So I emailed my web host. They reply with: "The only restriction we have is that our servers don't allow loopback connections (i.e. network connections back to themselves).". This is my problem I'm assuming?

Comment: @Acidic Correctamundo ;) But as I said above, it shouldn't be necessary anyway.

Comment: @Acidic Correct, if they have a firewall rule in place that prevents the host from connecting back to itself over the public Internet, then you would more than likely encounter this `connection reset by peer` error, since it is the very local network  system error that is commonly encountered when the systems detects and fails the datastream connection at a lower level than that of the software stack.

Comment: @Sherif Still this cannot be a firewall issue. It happens, when the server closes the connection without having read all the data, which the host already received on the network layer. The firewall would have prevented the connect already. In this case, the webserver provably closes the (already  opened) connection without reading the request.

Comment: @Ctx That's not necessarily true in all cases. Depending on what level the firewall rule is implemented (hardware/software) and what proxying is done between them, there could very well be a transmission control block established at the TCP/IP layer before the remote host terminates the connection.

Comment: @Ctx and according to the OP, it is indeed a firewall issue given that their host admits the do not allow the external loopback connection. _i.e._ they are likely blocking this via some internal NAT.